# Casting a NULL value

Tags: c#, dbnull

I'm trying to populate a class object with values from a database table. The `someObject.Property` field is a nullable int type.

```
someObject.Property = Convert.ToInt32(dbReader["SomeField"]);
```

So, if `SomeField` is `null`, `Convert` will give a `DBNull` error. Is there a specific method I should be using for this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should work...

```
someObject.Property = dbReader["SomeField"].Equals(DBNull.Value)
    ? null
    : (Int32)dbReader["SomeField"];
```

`@John` - Good catch. Edit to reflect that oversight.

Comment: -1: DBNull is a type, not a value. You need to compare to `DBNull.Value`. And you'd do better to use `IsDbNull`.

Answer (score 3):

This method may be useful for what you're trying to do. It will try and parse the column value into it's respective type, and if it can't it will the return the types default value.

```
public T ParseValue<T>(System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader reader, string column)
{
     T result = default(T);
     int index = reader.GetOrdinal(column);
     if (!reader.IsDBNull(index))
         result = (T)reader.GetValue(index);

     return result;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I use this, replacing `0` with whatever default. If the property is `nullable` then you would default to the C# `null`.

```
someObject.Property = (DBNull.Value.Equals(dbReader["SomeField"])) ? 0 : Convert.ToInt32(dbReader["SomeField"]);
```

Comment: His property is an `Int32?` so probably `null` is preferred. Otherwise same idea. =)

Comment: Whoops, missed that in your post. He did state "The someObject.Property field is a nullable int type."

Answer (score 1):

There is `TryParse`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx

You can also look at using the null coalescing operator `??` to give a default value if needed.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx). This won't specifically check for NULLs but it will tell you whether it is parseable or not which is probably what you really want.

```
bool result = Int32.TryParse(value, out number);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
if (reader["SomeField"] != DBNull.Value)
    someObject.Property = reader.GetInt32(dbReader("SomeField"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int someFieldIndex = reader.GetOrdinal("SomeField");
someObject.Property = reader.IsDbNull(someFieldIndex) ? null : (Int32?)reader.GetInt32(someFieldIndex);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
someObject.Property = Convert.ToInt32(dbReader["SomeField"].ToString());
```